# Handling exception when there are multiple sql queries to be fired

Tags: python, mariadb, pymysql, try-except, dbconnection

I am fetching data from database using four select queries. The data is in such a way that there are cases when the input to select query may be empty. In that case it is okay for that particular select statement to not work. In short, what I want is that the four select statements should fire and whichever statements work should work irrespective of other query getting failed.

```
try:
    cur.execute("select IP_ADD,VENDOR,DVC_ROLE,CIRCLE,SSA,REGION from DVC_SUMMARY_DATA where IP_ADD in (%s);" % ip_i)

except Exception as e:
    print("error while fetching details " + str(e))

result_i = cur.fetchall()

try:
    cur.execute("select IP_ADD,VENDOR,DVC_ROLE,CIRCLE,SSA,REGION from DVC_SUMMARY_DATA where IP_ADD in (%s);" % ip_n)

except Exception as e:
    print("error while fetching details " + str(e))

result_n = cur.fetchall()

try:
    cur.execute("select IP_ADD,VENDOR,DVC_ROLE,CIRCLE,SSA,REGION from DVC_SUMMARY_DATA where IP_ADD in (%s);" % ip_c)

except Exception as e:
    print("error while fetching details " + str(e))

result_c = cur.fetchall()

try:
    cur.execute("select IP_ADD,VENDOR,DVC_ROLE,CIRCLE,SSA,REGION from DVC_SUMMARY_DATA where IP_ADD in (%s);" % ip_b)

except Exception as e:
    print("error while fetching details " + str(e))

result_b = cur.fetchall()
```

Comment: but if an exception occurs, you'll still perform a `fetchall` ?

Comment: Use a `for` loop!

Comment: Put the `ip_x` values in a list and iterate through it. Side note: don't use string formatting to build queries.

Comment: create a loop and store the fetchall results in a `list`.

Comment: @mash If someone's answer helped you then please upvote / accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes just put it in a for loop.

```
ip_list = [ip_i, ip_n, ip_c, ip_b]
result_list = []

for ip in ip_list:
    try:
        cur.execute("select IP_ADD,VENDOR,DVC_ROLE,CIRCLE,SSA,REGION from DVC_SUMMARY_DATA where IP_ADD in (%s);" % ip)

    except Exception as e:
        print("error while fetching details " + str(e))        

    result_list.append(cur.fetchall())
```

I am guessing that cur.fetchall() does not generate an error, if it does or you don't want it to run then you can put it inside the try one.

So I would change it to this to keep track of which generated errors;

```
ip_list = [ip_i, ip_n, ip_c, ip_b]
result_list = []

for ip in ip_list:
    try:
        cur.execute("select IP_ADD,VENDOR,DVC_ROLE,CIRCLE,SSA,REGION from DVC_SUMMARY_DATA where IP_ADD in (%s);" % ip)
        result_list.append(cur.fetchall())

    except Exception as e:
        print("error while fetching details " + str(e))  
        result_list.append("ERROR")
```

Comment: `result_list.append(cur.fetchall())` will fail on an exception, or may give duplicate values

Comment: ah I thought it didn't since that's what he's doing in his original code

Comment: Hmm, I guess we could assume the cursor is global. I still think the `append` should be done inside the `try` so that they fail together rather than trying to call `fetchall()` if the query fails.

Comment: I mean this can easily be fixed by just moving the append to after the cur.execute inside the try

Comment: Yep, which is what I'm suggesting you edit in your answer :)

Comment: but I don't think that it would generate an error, otherwise his code would never have worked, no?

Comment: Basically he just asked how to shorten it, so I figured to keep it as similar as possible

Comment: They don't actually append anything in their code, and just because the OP had that setup to begin with doesn't mean it's the correct approach. Maybe they've just not encountered an exception so far, and will later find that their code fails. If you are aware of a better way of handling the flow, I would recommend that you update your answer to reflect it, it's not an incomprehensible change from what they have and definitely an improvement

Answer (score 0):

Add your IP address variables to a list and then iterate over the list. Here I'm using the `traceback` module to print an entire stack trace (not just the exception) and I'm also doing the `fetchall` within the `try` block, otherwise, if an exception does occur during the `execute` you'd be trying to fetch nothing.

```
import traceback

ip_list = [ ip_i, ip_n, ip_c, ip_b ]

for ip in ip_list:
    try:
        cur.execute("select IP_ADD,VENDOR,DVC_ROLE,CIRCLE,SSA,REGION from DVC_SUMMARY_DATA where IP_ADD in (%s);" % ip)

        result = cur.fetchall()

    except Exception as e:
        print(traceback.format_exc())
```